# Button's text is only half visible

Tags: android, button, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I am having troulbe fixing the following issue. I have a button with text OK. The button is nested inside a `LinearLayout`. This layout is nested inside two `RelativeLayout`. The second/inner `RelativeLayout` has `android:layout_margin="15dp". This is causing the text inside the button to be only half visible. 
The XML is below. I am using it because it gives me the "popup" dialog with the (X) button on the top right corner.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp" 
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/xml_round_corners_background"
        >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" 
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/xml_round_corners_background"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"

                >
                <LinearLayout 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" 
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    >
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/exitTV"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:text="TEXT....\n\n\n" 
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                    />
               </LinearLayout>

               <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:id="@+id/bluetooth_error_button_linearlayout"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" 
                    android:layout_below="@+id/exitTV"
                    >
                    <Button
                        android:layout_margin="15dp" 
                        android:id="@+id/bt_error_message_ok_button"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/xml_botton1"
                        android:text="OK"
                        android:textColor="@color/DarkMagenta" />
                </LinearLayout>



            </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/bt_error_message_x_button"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
        android:text="X"
        android:textColor="#FFF" 
        android:background="@drawable/xml_round_dismiss_button"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="7sp" 
        android:layout_height="30sp"
        android:layout_width="30sp" 
        android:textSize="15sp" 
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:onClick="cancelActivity" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Could anyone please tell me what can i do to make the text fully visible?
I have changed/addded/removed attributes to the `LinearLayout` and the `RelativeLayout` the `TextView`, and the `Button` as well. but I could not make it work.

Thanks

EDIT:
This photo is how Eclipse shows the window, and its actually how I want it to be. 
[image: photo 1]

This is a partial screen shot from my phone. Samsumg Galaxy S III mini (4.0" screen)
[image: photo 2]

Comment: can you post a screenshot

Comment: First, I think you have too many `Layouts` for 3 `Views` you should be able to accomplish this with one, maybe two, `Layouts`.

Comment: show us what you want...and what you are getting...

Comment: I just added the photos

Comment: Any one has any ideas as to how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I jsut realized that I was using another XML file as the background for each button. This XML was causing those issues.

Answer (score 0):

rather than try to "text" with "background" in your XML, try using drawableTop (or ~Left ~Right or ~Bottom).   These set the text so that the drawable is above "drawableTop" your text or where ever you want it

Comment: I am not fully sure what you are trying to offer here. Sorry. Can you give an example?

Comment: <Button
                 android:id="@+id/notebutton"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="0.25"
                 android:b="@drawable/xml_round_dismiss_button"
                 android:text="@string/note_title" >

Comment: I am not trying to modify the round (X) button. If you will review the  images I added above, you will see that the "OK" button is supposed to be all seen (Graphical View), but when I run it on my phone, the text it cut in half. Any ideas?